# How can I display total order amount and each order amount in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 4 tables which are `customer`, `customerOrder`, `Orderitems`, and `Produceitems`.

Each order may have more than 1 item, so I have already calculated  total item cost for each item that a customer has ordered, but I don't know how to display the total order amount for that order, in the same table.

**Picture Of Database Table**:

[image: Picture Of Database Table]

**Code**:

```
SELECT CustomerName,
       CustomerID AS Account_Number,
       OrderID,
       OrderDate,
       ItemName,
       ItemQty,
       ItemCost AS Price,
       UnitShippingCost*ItemQty AS Shipping_Cost,
       (ItemCost+UnitShippingCost)*ItemQty AS Item_total_cost
FROM CustomerOrder
INNER JOIN OrderItems USING (OrderID)
INNER JOIN ProduceItems USING (ItemID)
INNER JOIN Customer USING (CustomerID)
WHERE CustomerOrder.OrderID='OD00561';
```

how can I add one more column named total_order_amount in the table and rest of column remain the same? Order OD00561 total amount will be the sum of 3 Item cost.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You need window functions . . . .

```
SELECT . . .
       SUM(UnitShippingCost*ItemQty) OVER () AS Shipping_Cost,
       SUM((ItemCost+UnitShippingCost)*ItemQty) OVER () AS Item_total_cost
FROM CustomerOrder co INNER JOIN
     OrderItems oi
     USING (OrderID) INNER JOIN
     ProduceItems pi
     USING (ItemID)
WHERE co.OrderID = 'OD00561';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still need customer name, order id, items, item and all the other attributes in the table, the problem is I can't display the total order amount (sum(total_item_cost)) in the same table because the same orderID. I tried to use nested select but still doesn'w work

Comment: @Ceci: you can replace the `. . .` in the query with the list of columns you want.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thank you, but still, there are only has total amount of the order, but no total item cost of each item that customer ordered. lets say total amount of OD00561 is 3337.5, but total item_cost of item Vegetable Box is 2040, fruit box is 600, Mushroom is 697.50

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: and shipping cost for each item are different, not sum of each shipping cost:(

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agNNF.png     can you see the pic, I just want to add 1 more column as Order_total_amount, and the rest of the columns remains the same